# android get foreground application from service does not detect floating widget

Tags: android, facebook, service, foreground

I am trying to get what current application is running in the foreground of my android phone from a service.
this task was solved by this code:

```
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(mContext.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // The first in the list of RunningTasks is always the foreground task.
        RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
        String foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo.topActivity
                .getPackageName();
        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo foregroundAppPackageInfo;
        Log.d("dd", "test2");
        try {
            foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(
                    foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);
            String foregroundTaskAppName = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo
                    .loadLabel(pm).toString();
            Log.d("aaa", foregroundTaskAppName);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("aaa", "error");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

however, when i open facebook chat floating widget 
(that circle with your friends icon on it),
 the foreground application written is the one below it. how can i solve this?

Comment: Note that `getRunningTasks()` is deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview and should remain deprecated in future versions of Android, making it unusable for your use case. Moreover, Facebook "chatheads" are not a task.